# CSS: Text over image with reduced opacity should not have reduced opacity

Tags: css, opacity

I have an image which has reduced opacity and some text, which is in a separate div, which is lying over the image (negative margin-top). While the image should be transparent, the text should not. I now found out that, depending on the value of the opacity the text is shown in black or also transparent.

When the image has

> opacity: 1

the text ist black, when the value lower - the text has an reduced opacity as well. 
My markup looks like this:

```
<li>
    <img src="image.jpg">
    <div class="text">Description</div>
</li>

.text{ margin-top: -3em; }
img{ opacity: 0.5; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BFhau/1/

How can I display the text always in black?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
position: relative;
```

to place text at the top.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/BFhau/3/)

---

The problem was setting `opacity` different than `1` creates an stacking context.

Then, according to [the order defined in the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/zindex.html#painting-order), images overlap texts, because:

- (4) `.text` are in-flow, non-positioned, block-level elements
- (6) Images are inline elements that generate a stacking context

Since 4 < 6, images overlap text.

To avoid that, you can make `.text` positioned elements adding `position: relative`. Now they will fall into this category:

- (8) Positioned descendants with 'z-index: auto' or 'z-index: 0'

Now, since 6 < 8, texts overlap images.

Alternatively, you could also add a positive `z-index` (e.g. `z-index:1`) in order to make `.text` fall into the next category:

- (9) Stacking contexts formed by positioned descendants with z-indices greater than or equal to 1

You can read more about stacking contexts and z-axis positioning in [What No One Told You About Z-Index](http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/), a great article much more appealing than the raw spec.